# How can I callback the rules tuple when I go to the next page of the website

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

from urllib import parse
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

class DetailsSpider(CrawlSpider):
name = 'details'
start_urls = ['https://www.insiderpages.com','https://www.insiderpages.com/search/search?query=doctors&location=San+Francisco%2C+CA&commit=Go%21']

```
def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url,meta={"x":"1"})

rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=("//h2[@class='pixel-tracking']/a")), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
)

def parse_item(self, response):        
    yield{
        'Title':response.xpath("//h1[@class='org fn business_card_name name']/span/text()").get(),
        'Address':response.xpath("//span[@class='adr address']/p/span/text()").get(),
        'City':response.xpath("//span[@class='adr address']/p[2]/span/text()").get(),
        'State':response.xpath("//span[@class='adr address']/p[2]/span[2]/text()").get(),
        'Postal Code':response.xpath("//span[@class='adr address']/p[2]/span[3]/text()").get(),
        'Phone':response.xpath("//li[@class='telephone']/strong/p/text()").get(),
        'Email':response.xpath("//li[@class='email']/a/@href").get(),
    }
    x = int(response.meta['x'])
    if x!=10:
        yield scrapy.Request(url="https://www.insiderpages.com/s/CA/SanFrancisco/Doctors?cs_category=Doctors&page="+str(x)+"&radius=0", callback=self.parse_item,meta={"x":str(x+1)})
```

Comment: Down- voting; please provide a question. What is your issue? What do you expect?

Comment: you need to explain the question

Comment: I want to have the rules inside a function so that I could callback it whenever I want

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to call the tuple when I go to the next page